# How to pass targetType parameter to the Convert() method of the IValueConverter instance in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Converter method of the IValueConverter instance can get some parameters:

```
Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture);
```

How to pass targetType parameter from XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't pass targetType, the framework does so for you, depending on what type it needs converted into.

Consider the StringFormatConverter from Template 10: https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki/Converters

```
<Page.Resources>
    <converters:StringFormatConverter x:Key="StrFormatConverter" />    
</Page.Resources>
...
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DateTimeValue, Converter={StaticResource StrFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter=\{0:D\}}" />
```

In this case, the system needs a String, so it will pass 'String' in as the targetType parameter.

You should confirm that the type its expecting is the type you're prepared to convert into.